# Drawing into a LinearLayout

Tags: android, image, android-linearlayout, tablerow

I'm trying to draw an image into a LinearLayout, or TableRow, but I'm having already a XML FILE (I want to draw inside some LinearLayout). I don't know exactly how to do it. I was trying this:

```
    TableRow mytable = (TableRow) findViewById(R.id.tablatexto);
    ImageView myImage = (ImageView) findViewById(R.drawable.personaje1);
    mytable.addView(myImage);
```

Thanks

Editing: I want to explaint it better. What I want to is creating a animation drawing images depending of a thread. So, I want to draw to some in LinearLayout from the Activity.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you wan't to add dynamic layout in the container layout then you can use [`containerLayout.addView(childView);`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/ViewGroup.html#addView%28android.view.View,%20int,%20android.view.ViewGroup.LayoutParams%29)

childView is the dynamic layout which you can create using code or you can get a view of the layout using [`LayoutInflater`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/LayoutInflater.html) class.

Comment: I don't get how can I use 'R.drawable.personaje1' (image in the drawable folder) into my 'R.id.tablatexto' (tablerow in my xml file)

Thanks for the answer.

Comment: I am not getting your requirement. Can you post your xml file so that I can understand ?